# Localization with resource file not working when setting culture at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I'm setting the page culture at runtime in the code-behind like this:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
Page.Culture = "fr-FR";
```

The resource files are in the GlobalResource folder and I've got 2 files: `SomeFile.resx` and `SomeFile.fr.resx`

In the markup page, I have a literal that looks like this:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="test" Text="<%$ Resources:SomeFile, SomeKey%>" />
```

If the code that sets the culture is commented out then the literal will take the value that's in the `SomeFile.resx` but if I run the code that sets the culture then I also get the value that's in the `SomeFile.resx` file instead of the value that's in the `SomeFile.fr.resx` file. I also tried with the culture info set to just "fr" to see if that makes any difference but it doesn't.

What do I need to change?

Comment: Does getting string from resources work correctly immediately after setting culture (something like `var s = SomeResources.SomeKey;`, assuming you have auo-generation turned on for resx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for those who come here, I've figured it out.

1) Put the resource files in the `App_GlobalResources` folder. For example, you might have `SomeFile.resx` and `SomeFile.fr.resx`

2) In your code behind, set the culture like this:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
Page.Culture = "fr-FR";
```

3) Then, to access the values, you write this:

```
string SomeValue = GetGlobalResourceObject("SomeFile", "SomeKey").ToString();
```

I think is is the simplest way to do it.

Comment: Not to complain, but this is nearly identical to the answer I provided two hours earlier. Why is this the answer marked correct?

Comment: frenchie, the post is a bit old but do you set the culture for example in the controller, also I guess if this is the correct way the culture will be changed for all requested views after.. then maybe store the culture in some cookie or session variable or something

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s9ckwb4b(v=vs.100).aspx) for locating localized resources provides a good example of how to do this. From what you've written, it looks like you are not creating a new `ResourceManager` object to use the culture:

```
private ResourceManager rm { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load()
{
  var newCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;
  Page.Culture = "fr-FR";
  this.rm = new ResourceManager("SomeFile", typeof(Program).Assembly);

  this.test.Text = rm.GetString("SomeKey");
}
```

Comment: This line is causing problems: this.rm = new ResourceManager("SomeFile", typeof(Program).Assembly); It's for desktop apps and I've got an asp.net app.

Comment: Upvoted because your solution got me on the right track.

Comment: I've used `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` instead of `typeof(Program).Assembly`